# C# Linq-to-SQL update multiple values not saving

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a simple enough update statement that does not seems to be working.

```
try
{
    AdventureWorksDataContext k = new AdventureWorksDataContext(@"Data Source = UKFOLONLAP0255\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = AdventureWorks2014; User ID = sa; Password = #######");

    k.TOP_STANDARD_COSTs.ToList().ForEach(t => {                   
               t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    });

    k.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

The value of `t.Id` only remains while in the foreach loop. As soon as the debugger gets out from the loop the value becomes null. I tried to put submit changes inside the loop but with no joy.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the context that the data is modified.

```
foreach(var t in k.TOP_STANDARD_COSTs)
{
    t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    k.Entry(t).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
}
k.SubmitChanges();
```

Note that is not efficient code if number of records is significant. It is better to execute this update on the sql server side.

```
k.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update TOP_STANDARD_COSTs set Id=newid()")
```

Comment: Took the second option. Because k do not have any object called Entry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
try
    {
        using (AdventureWorksDataContext k = new AdventureWorksDataContext(@"Data Source = UKFOLONLAP0255\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = AdventureWorks2014; User ID = sa; Password = #######"))
        {
            foreach(var t in k.TOP_STANDARD_COSTs)
            {
                t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }

            k.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided, my guess us that you are trying to assign the value `Guid.NewGuid()` to each object's ID property in `k.TOP_STANDARD_COSTs`. Assuming that I have understood your question correctly, this can be achieved via a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach(var t in k.TOP_STANDARD_COSTs)
{
    t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
}
k.SubmitChanges();
```

The reason why you cannot get the t.Id value outside of the foreach loop is because the scope of that particular variable lies within the scope of the loop only. Once you have updated the Id property of the objects in the list, you can update your changes in the database.

Comment: @imranchowdhury could you share the class definition for `TOP_STANDARD_COSTs`? Also, you can try `SaveChanges()` instead of `SubmitChanges()`